# How to launch executable after installation (exe is delivered by .msm)

Tags: wix, custom-action

I did everything as explained in [tutorial](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html), but my executable wasn't launched after product installation completed.
There is a nuance that my executable is delivered with .msm module, so in .wxs file for .msi I do the following to launch application:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product>
    <!-- I omit here features and elements which are irrelevant to the question-->
    <Feature Id="Configurator" Display="hidden" Level="1">
        <MergeRef Id="MergeConfigurator"/>
    </Feature>
    <UI>
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal"/>
        <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction"
                 Value="LaunchConfigurator">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
    </UI>
    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="!(loc.ExitDlgCheckBoxText)" />
    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX" Value="1"/>
    <Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#SystemConfigurator.exe.81c0fa8f-9a8e-49d8-9dc2-ce01ca163146]" />
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchConfigurator" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
</Product>
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
        <Merge Id="MergeConfigurator" SourceFile="$(var.MergeModulesPath)\ConfiguratorSetup_$(var.Platform).msm" DiskId="1" Language="1033"/>
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

For the property with Id=WixShellExecTarget I have tried to pass value both with and without GUID (this is Package/@Id of .msm with my executable).
I opened my .msi with Orca and saw the exact ID of my executable (it's SystemConfigurator.exe.81c0fa8f-9a8e-49d8-9dc2-ce01ca163146, that's why I pass this very value).

But what it's wrong?

I logged installation process using /l*v option, and there is a portion from log:

```
Action 18:47:57: LaunchConfigurator. 
Action start 18:47:57: LaunchConfigurator.
MSI (c) (54:68) [18:47:58:106]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\AAGENO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\MSIB233.tmp, Entrypoint: WixShellExec
MSI (c) (54:08) [18:47:58:106]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (54:08) [18:47:58:106]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (54:08) [18:47:58:106]: Connected to service for CA interface.
MSI (c) (54!04) [18:47:58:476]: Note: 1: 2715 2: SystemConfigurator.Client.exe.81c0fa8f-9a8e-49d8-9dc2-ce01ca163146 
MSI (c) (54!04) [18:47:58:476]: Note: 1: 2715 2: SystemConfigurator.Client.exe.81c0fa8f-9a8e-49d8-9dc2-ce01ca163146 
Action ended 18:47:58: LaunchConfigurator. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (54:34) [18:47:58:476]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (54:34) [18:47:58:476]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2896 
DEBUG: Error 2896:  Executing action LaunchConfigurator failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 2715 means that the file key you're using isn't actually in the file table. Assuming it's referring to SystemConfigurator.exe.81c0fa8f-9a8e-49d8-9dc2-ce01ca163146 I would open the MSI file with Orca and see if that is the correct value AND keep in mind that Windows Installer proiperties are case-sensitive so if if it really is upper-case then use upper case.  Make sure it really is a dash too, and not an underscore.

Comment: Thanks, I checked MSI file with Orca - GUID's part of file key is really upper-case and with underscores. I fixed value for WixShellExecTarget property - now it works. But... can I be ensured that in MSI file table GUID is always uppercase and with underscores?

Comment: Dashes are not legal in MSI Property names, and public properties are required to be uppercase, and I think the merge APIs produce uppercase and underscores, so I believe you are safe.